# Playing sounds in Xcode while playing music from apps

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am currently using the following code to play music within my Xcode project. However, when I play music, other music apps (eg: spotify) stop playing. I understand there is AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, but i am not to sure how to set this function within my code.

How do i play music within my app without stopping music from other apps that are currently playing?

Any help would be much appreciated :D

Thanks!

```
import UIKit

import AVFoundation


let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


  /* MUSIC */

var musicIsPlaying: Bool = false
var bgMusicLoop: AVAudioPlayer!

func playBackgroundMusic(fileName: String, withExtenstion fileExtension: String) {


    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate


    if appDelegate.musicIsPlaying == false {

        appDelegate.musicIsPlaying = true

        let filePath: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileExtension)!

        if (appDelegate.bgMusicLoop != nil) {
            appDelegate.bgMusicLoop.stop()
        }
        appDelegate.bgMusicLoop = nil

        do {

            appDelegate.bgMusicLoop = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath))

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        //A negative means it loops forever
        appDelegate.bgMusicLoop.numberOfLoops = -1
        appDelegate.bgMusicLoop.prepareToPlay()
        appDelegate.bgMusicLoop.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)` to your code.

`AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` "plays sounds that add polish or interest but are not essential to the app’s use."

Comment: Awesome! That was very easy haha Thanks for your help! Cheers! :D :D :D